# Retrying SQLSTATE XX000 in YugabyteDB

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Just got this error message while running my query:

```
Network error: recvmsg got EOF from remote (SQLSTATE XX000)
```

Is this error retryable?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should treat this as a timeout error against any DB. The app should retry this type of error - but it is possible that the previous operation already succeeded.. .and for example, you could get a `duplicate primary key` error (if you are say retrying an INSERT).

In this particular case though, our expectation is that mostly like there was a yb-tserver restart or connection failure or partition of some kind.